# JS: Fastest way to create all substrings starting at index 0

Tags: javascript, performance, substring

So I'm looking for a way to generate all possible substrings from a larger String that start at index 0. So let's say we have

```
var a = "test";
```

Then I want to generate

```
"test", "tes", "te" and "t"
```

I imagine doing this with substring, substr or slice, and I tested them here: http://jsperf.com/loop-over-string

Now the slice method seems almost *twice* as fast as the other methods. Can anybody explain that? Or is there even faster ways to do this?

Comment: Added the constraint from the title (*starting at index 0*) to the question body.

Comment: In Firefox on Linux it's only about 35% faster.

Comment: But I still find that a significant speed improvement... Any clues?

Comment: It's not consistently faster across browsers.  Looking at the chart now, it about the same in IE9, significantly slower in FF26, significantly faster in FF23, and a lot faster in Chrome.  I wouldn't read much into these numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your benchmark `slice` is faster because `text`'s length decreases each iteration.

If you take a look at `substr`, `substring` and `slice` implementations in V8 you will realize that they use the same internal function `%_SubString`. They only manipulate its parameters at a negligible cost.

- `String.prototype.slice`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/string.js#L567
- `String.prototype.substring`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/string.js#L713
- `String.prototype.substr`: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/string.js#L748

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be faster:

```
substr = ""
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    substr += text.charAt(i)
}
```

http://jsperf.com/loop-over-string/3

Comment: Smart implementation, minimizes the amount of lookups; thanks!

Comment: Added the reverse (which is what I want) also : http://jsperf.com/loop-over-string/6